# In the pytabular package, how do you access the value of a cell?

Tags: python, package

Sorry for such a basic question, but how do you access the value of a pytabular tabular? I am not seeing the method in the tutorial or the source. My current work around is to output the value as tex and convert it to a float but I was wondering if there was a more elegent way to achieve this result

Minimum Example:

```
import numpy as np

import pytabular as pytab

data = np.random.randn(3,4)

table=pytab.Tabular(data)

float(table[1][1].as_tex())
```

Edit:

Figured it out. There is a .content command that will output the value. In this case, just use table[1][1].content

Comment: Ah! Figured it out. There is a .content command which will achieve this result. I will leave the question up in case there are others who are confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pytabular dev here. The package should have a method to access the contents of a cell. We will probably include this in a future release. But as of now, accessing the "content" attribute seems to solve your problem. But just as a reminder, "content" is an attribute and not a method of the cell instance.